# Calendar List View "Jump to previous or next date range" not working correctly

Tags: calendar-view

Created a list calendar view but the "Jump to previous or next date range" either doesn't work or will show the previous month instead of the month selected. I have tried deleting the view entirely and recreating the view with no change. The up/down arrows work as expected. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I just tried [creating a modern calendar view in SharePoint list](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/) and it is working fine for me. Can you try creating another test list in same site and see if you can replicate the issue?

Comment: I created another test list/calendar view and observing the same issue. However when I try it in a completely different SP site, it works as expected. So I guess its a higher level issue than just the list itself?

Comment: Maybe regional or language setting? Can you compare these settings for both the sites?

Comment: Interesting! Comparing the regional settings showed that when the time zone is set to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time it presents the problem. When the time zone is set to any other time zone, it works perfectly. Is this a bug or something that I can fix?

Comment: What's your current / local timezone? Can you try using it & see if it works for you? It might be the bug from Microsoft's side.

Comment: Yes, I tried with other time zones and it worked like its supposed to. I guess this is just a bug within Microsofts side..

Comment: I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly. Follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried [creating a modern calendar view in SharePoint list](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/) and it is working fine for me.

I think the issue is with regional settings on your SharePoint site. As mentioned in comments section above, this issue is because time zone is set to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time.

It might be the bug from Microsoft's side. So, I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly. Follow this documentation for the same: [Get support for Microsoft 365 - online support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)